# What's the error in this simple AngularJS calculator?

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS newbie here. I'm trying to make a very simple calculator that adds two values in Angular 1.5. The value of `calc.result` doesn't update.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="Calculator">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="calcCtrl as calc">
        <input type="number" ng-model="calc.input1">
         <span>+</span>
        <input type="number" ng-model="calc.input2">
         <span>=</span>
        <input type="number" ng-model="calc.result">
    </div>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/calc.js"></script>
</body>
```

**js/app.js**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('Calculator', []);
})();
```

**js/controllers/calc.js**

```
(function() {
    angular
    .module('Calculator')
    .controller('calcCtrl', CalculatorControl);

    function CalculatorControl()
    {
        this.input1 = 0;
        this.input2 = 0;

        this.result = this.input1 + this.input2;
    }
})();
```

Comment: put a  watch using timeout on 'this.result' variable to get the latest value

Comment: in third input tag call the caluclate function by sending the values and return result from function and display it in input tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a computed property to access a value that is dependent on other properties on the controller / scope.

To achieve it, javascript gives you the ability to have a getter on object, that you could use to compute the value, but still can access it as a property, in your case its result.

You could read more about [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on MDN.

Here is what you could do.

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('Calculator', []);
})();

(function() {
  angular
    .module('Calculator')
    .controller('calcCtrl', CalculatorControl);

  function CalculatorControl() {
    this.input1 = 0;
    this.input2 = 0;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'result', {
      get: function() {
        return this.input1 + this.input2;
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Calculator">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="calcCtrl as calc">
    <input type="number" ng-model="calc.input1">
    <span>+</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="calc.input2">
    <span>=</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="calc.result" ng-disabled="true" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply change one row:

```
<span>=</span>
<input type="number" ng-value="calc.input1*1 + calc.input2*1">
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but I want to achieve it with a controller.

Answer (score 2):

Make `result` as a function which will be calculation of `input1` & `input2`. Also it doesn't make sense to edit result part by user, so instead of result as `input` field make it display only field.

**Markup**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="calcCtrl as calc">
    <input type="number" ng-model="calc.input1">
     <span>+</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="calc.input2">
     <span>=</span>
    <span ng-bind="calc.result()"></span>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function CalculatorControl() {
    var self = this;
    self.input1 = 0;
    self.input2 = 0;

    self.result = function(){ 
      var input1 = !isNaN(self.input1) ? self.input1: 0,
          input2 = !isNaN(self.input2) ? self.input2: 0;
      return input1 + input2;
    }
}
```

[**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AfGSKqRlvcr1GN8a8gCu?p=preview)

Comment: I downvoted because your solution was erroneous. Now that it's fixed, I've taken back the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: @anonym solution doesn't work, doesn't mean that you should downvote it.. If the idea behind the answer is incorrect/pathetic then only downvote... and this is how people do downvote

Comment: You can't expect a newbie to comprehend if an idea behind an answer is incorrect. You should not provide a wrong solution without testing the code first, before trying to help. Would you want your junior to learn something wrong, just so that you can answer quickly and earn some points? An erroneous code, imo, is worth a downvote.

Comment: @anonym I agreed with what you are saying(but in this case it doesn't seems to be case of downvote), SO is place where people come to get direction with what they are doing & sometimes answer-er just to give brighter idea about solution..

Comment: Well I did take back the downvote upon realizing you sincerely re-edited the question upon my comment. Perspectives differ, my friend. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not calling the add function on a click event.

Then you are initializing the values of every function call.

You will need to do the addition in a separate method.